# CDF of a continuous and discrete random variable - attributes

Tags: random-variables, definition, cumulative-distribution-functions

Something that bothers me as I was just doing an exercise.
We know that the CDF of a function must be:

1. Continuous from right side.
2. Monotonic up.
3. The limit at infinity is 1.
4. The limit at minus infinity is 0.

But if the random variable is discrete, then the CDF does not apply that? ( at least according to an exercise in a test ).
Searched here for other topics of the same, could not find.
Is there a different definition for continuous random variable, discrete random variable and not discrete\continuous random variable, for the CDF?
If yes, please do tell me so, which attributes to which random variable it apply ( discrete, continuous, neither) and if there any extra attributes, I will be happy to hear

EDIT: Example of such:
$$F_X\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}0&t<\pi \\ \frac{1}{3}\:&\pi \le t<5\\ \frac{1}{2}\:&5\le t<10^6\\ \:1&t>10^6\end{cases}$$
And another one:
$$F_X\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}0&t<1\\ 1-\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)^t&t\ge 1\end{cases}$$
And such a case of that it is not a CDF:
$$F_X\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}2^{-⌊t⌋-1}&t<0\\ 1-2^{-⌊t⌋-1}&t\ge 0\end{cases}$$
That is at my test, american question, first two possibly be CDF, the last one, is not CDF
( Of course all are for X discrete ).

Final Edit for post:
I understood the solution, thanks for the comments!!

Comment: The CDF of any random variable satisfies the properties you listed. Conversely, any function satisfying those properties is the CDF of some random variable

Comment: The converse is much harder to prove. For the forwards implication, just apply the basic properties of measure, I.e. monotonicty of measure and continuity of measure.

Comment: Oh I dont need to proof, I want to understand.   since it does not satisfy, I will edit and @you once its here. ........ it just feels so weird and no idea why, first time meeting such a thing

Comment: @Andrew Done, hope it will be more clear now, my problem

Comment: Any RV, regardless discrete or continuous, should have a CDF that satisfies those properties. Perhaps there is a typo in your last example, since if it were $2^{\lfloor t \rfloor-1}$ for $t<0$ then it would satisfy $\lim_{t\to -\infty} F(t)=0$. Otherwise, as written, the limit is $\infty$, so the given function cannot be a CDF of any RV.

Comment: Sadly, there is not any typo, I will edit and try to upload a picture ( if it is possible ) @NapD.Lover

Comment: Hi, apparently, I was pretty much an "idiot", I just understood how to do the solution........ I did not notice the continuance from right correctly, that was what make me not understand. 
Thanks!!